# Im looking to create a specific drop down menu (example included)

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, responsive-design

I'm looking to understand how to code drop down navigation bar similar to the reference site included below. Their solution works perfectly between pc/mac/iphone and android and it would be awesome if someone can show me the same. If you are looking at this site via your pc or mac adjust the size of the browser to activate the drop down version of the navigation. Thanks alot!

http://treadsack.com/

p.s Im new to asking these questions online so if you need me to be more specific please comment and I will comment back.

Thanks again!

Comment: If you end up using Bootstrap 3, here's a version of that menu. http://jsbin.com/UnEKuDiY/3/

Comment: @cab is there a good tutorial that shows how to use bootstrap? seems like an easy option and great tool to know. I know how to code html and css so any tutorial that will show me how to integrate would be amazing. thanks.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com has nearly everything you need plus Googling. There's a lot of users who write stuff all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Just use bootstrap, http://getbootstrap.com Its allready cross browser compliant, and uses that type of menu

Comment: Upvoted this since it's the fastest. but if you don't know enough css the ability to center the links, add an image for the logo, and change out the icon would be quite a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to show the dropdown *like* that, assuming that's what you're asking. In this case, observe what they've done using the browser's tools.

In Chrome:

1. Minimize the browser, so you can see the dropdown style of the page.
2. Click on the "NAV" link to see the dropdown menu.
3. Right-click on any of those menu items, and click Inspect Element.
4. You'll see the Developer Tools open up below, showing the HTML. You'll notice that the element that you wanted to inspect, is a `<a>` inside `<li>` inside `<ul>` inside a `<div>` of class `dropdown`

   4.1 When the Nav is closed, this div is as below:

   ```
       <div class="dropdown" id="nav-dropdown" style="display: none;">
            <!-- bunch of ul, li elements follow here -->
       </div>
   ```
5. Now click on the Nav link, and observe the change in HTML of that `div` alone. You'll notice it as below:

   ```
       <div class="dropdown" id="nav-dropdown" style="display: block;">
            <!-- bunch of ul, li elements follow here -->
       </div>
   ```

They just changed the `display` property of the div, from `none` to `block` materializing all those menu items.

And *that* can be done using jquery as below:

```
 $( "#nav-trigger" ).click(function() {
       $('#dropdown').css("display", "block");
 });
```

`nav-trigger` is the id of the NAV element.

**Update:**

The HTML is structured like this:

```
<div class="main-container">
   <span class="navigation" id="nav-trigger"/>
   <div class="dropdown" display="none">
         <!-- menu items as <ul><li> here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

That's the main structure (names changed). Initially, only the `<span>` element is visible. When this `span` element is clicked, the `div` below it is displayed. So we associate a click handler to the `span` element in jQuery, as I've shown above. That's how they are "connected"

The animation:

Again, there are a lot of ways to do that. There are jQuery plugins that you can directly use in your project (easiest). Alternatively, you can use `jQuery.slideDown()` and `jQuery.slideUp()` to toggle the menu items down or up. Links: [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)  and [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

You'll notice that there is a sequence to the animation. Not all menu items are dropped down at once.

```
    $( "#nav-trigger" ).click(function() {
       var menuitems = $("#dropdown").children(); //since the items are hierarchically , children of the dropdown div.

       for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
            menuitems.eq(i).slideDown(200);   //200 is the speed.
       }
    });
```

That's a very crude code, but it gives you the picture. Hope that helps.

Comment: I know this might sound nood-ish but how where does "#nav-trigger" and '#dropdown' tie into the code? I understand how to make the list , list items, and link them I just don't know exactly what id to appoint to what and how the nav trigger and dropdown ids tie in. Thanks

Comment: also how do they do the slide down animations that happens? @sanjeevmk

Answer (score 0):

Basically, You can make sites mobile friendly by using percentages instead of set widths and heights... Typically developers will make separate styling sheets depending on device resolution... so at different resolutions content will scale accordingly. 
see this [example](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/mobile-css.htm)

This way you can control different styling so it displays correctly